# My XP computer is trying to boot into Linux

Tags: linux, security, virus, grub

This has happened twice now. I wake in the morning (yes noon is morning) I go to my computer to find it is stuck in the middle of rebooting. The last few lines of the log show the following.

```
GRUB loading stage 1.5.
GRUB loading, please wait...
Error 21
```

Isn't GRUB a bootloader for Linux? I've messed around with Ubuntu on this computer, but my last OS install was a clean format and install of XP. I've never actually seen this come up when I personally reset the computer, only a couple of times when it's reset on its own late at night.

I'm worried that I have some virus that is trying to reboot my computer into an instance of Linux that I didn't install. Has anyone seen something like this before? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MBR probably wasn't fixed correctly. A typical fixmbr [doesn't always fix things properly](http://www.techspot.com/vb/topic92514.html), but [MbrFix](http://download.cnet.com/MbrFix/3000-2094_4-10485990.html) is what I'd recommend. Simply use this command:

```
C:\path\to\mbrfix.exe /drive 0 fixmbr /yes
```

replace `C:\path\to` with the path to the mbrfix program.

Comment: now that sounds pretty scary, John: "However, users can accidentally delete partitions and important data."

Comment: If you specify the wrong drive. A windows CD isn't needed for this method either.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fix it?

boot from your Windows XP CD into the Recovery Condole and use the following command:

```
fixmbr
```